# Get custom data on button click in Webchat

Tags: botframework, web-chat

In Facebook messenger, buttons (on the cards as well), can send a custom payload, along with the text of the button which was clicked. This payload is available in the sourceEvent section of the message. Also this payload has to be added in the sourceEvent manually. There is no official Bot framework API available for doing this.

This is a sample payload on FB button

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/button-template

**My Chatbot also supports Webchat. Does Webchat supports sending such payload to the bot?** Right now all I get is the text of the button clicked.

Comment: For * There is no official Bot framework API available for doing this* you can see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37011994/3768871